# Issues using LatLng in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers

Hi I was able to get some guidance with the set up of this class initially but an error is occurring.  It is showing red under the comma when I try to put the LatLng into the creation of each object.  Can anyone tell me why? Am I missing a bracket or something or how do I format the LatLng when entering it into the creation of the object?

```
public class Cinema {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private HashMap cinemaMarker;

    String name;
    String webSite;
    LatLng position;

    public Cinema(String name, String webSite, LatLng position){
        this.name = name;
        this.webSite = webSite;
        this.position = position;
    }

public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getWebSite(){
        return webSite;
    }

    public LatLng getPosition(){
        return position;
    }

    public MarkerOptions getMarker(){
        return new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(name);
    }

    List<Cinema> cinemas = new ArrayList<>();

    public void MockData(){
        cinemas.add(new Cinema("ODEON","www.odeon.co.uk/films/", (54.598693,-5.925955));
        cinemas.add(new Cinema("Movie House -Dublin Rd","www.moviehouse.co.uk/Movie/Cinema/1/dublin_road", (54.592211, -5.931512));
        cinemas.add(new Cinema("Queen's Film Theatre","queensfilmtheatre.com/Whats-On", (54.585406, -5.933929));
        cinemas.add(new Cinema("Strand Cinema","www.cinemas-online.co.uk/films-out-now/", (54.600542, -5.879803 ));
        cinemas.add(new Cinema("Odyssey Cinema","www.odysseycinemas.co.uk/en.aspx", (54.603835, -5.916253));
        cinemas.add(new Cinema("Omniplex Kennedy Centre","www.omniplex.ie/", (54.580723, -5.979174));
        cinemas.add(new Cinema("Movie House - City Side","www.moviehouse.co.uk/Movie/Cinema/2/city_side", (54.608512, -5.926765));

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change all your lines in MockData in order to call the LatLng [contructor](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng):

```
cinemas.add(new Cinema("ODEON","www.odeon.co.uk/films/", new LatLng(54.598693,-5.925955))
```

**Public Constructor Summary**

`LatLng(double latitude, double longitude)`

Answer (score 1):

Use constructors in Java :)

```
cinemas.add(new Cinema("ODEON","www.odeon.co.uk/films/", new LatLng(54.598693,-5.925955));
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am also having issues adding the markers.  I have put this line of code in a new class and it says non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context...the error is on the getMarker() method...                                                                                   public void addMarkers(){
            //for each cinema
           cinemaMarker.put(googleMap.addMarker(Cinema.getMarker()), cinemas);

Comment: @user6176468 you can use static methods with class name, but non-static methods are provided for objects only. Call constructor of the your Cinema object, like new Cinema(params) and call getMarker() on this object

Comment: @user6176468 static methods can't keep reference to the object, this means, that they don't know, what is "position" and "title" which are used in the getMarker() method

Answer (score 0):

The parameter list you have for your method `Cinema` are-

1. String name 2. String webSite 3. LatLng position

So you have to pass these things into the method when you instanciate it. you are passing
`cinemas.add(new Cinema("ODEON","www.odeon.co.uk/films/", (54.598693,-5.925955));`

- the first parameter `"ODEON"` is string (Correct)
- the second parameter `"www.odeon.co.uk/films/"` is string (correct)
- the third parameter `(54.598693,-5.925955)` is not a latlng (incorrect)

so you have to pass a latlng in third parameter and to do this pass

`new LatLng(54.598693,-5.925955)` .

Hope this answer make you understand your fault.